# How to set RestFul Service using Azure API Management Service?

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm trying to create API Management operation using RestAPI like a `"/{x}/{y}/{z}.png"`
I don't want to `rewrite-url "x={x}&y={y}&z={z}.png"`.

How to set api config?

Please give me some advice and document's URL(ノДヽ) ・・

1. Add API
2. Set name ,API name,Service URL and API URL suffix
3. Set Operations ( method,URL template ,RESPONSES)

・original service url http://hogehoge/xyz/std/6/58/25.png

・using azure api management http://xxxxxxxxx.azure-api.net/xyz/std/6/58/25.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an API:

  - Web service URL: http://hogehoge/xyz/std/
  - Web API suffix: xyz/std
  - Web API URL scheme: check HTTP
- Create an operation:

  - Verb: GET
  - URL template: {x}/{y}/{z}.png
  - No rewrite URL

That should do it:

- When call is made to http://xxxxxxxxx.azure-api.net/xyz/std/6/58/25.png APIM will "bite off" scheme and host and be left with "xyz/std/6/58/25.png".
- It will check if path contains any of APIs suffixes, it does contain "xyz/std" so API will be matched and suffix will be "bitten off" again. What is left is "6/58/25.png".
- It will check if remainder of the path matches any operation template within identified API, it does match {x}/{y}/{z}.png, so operation is identified.
- It will take Web service URL from API settings and attach part of path that matched operation template to it getting http://hogehoge/xyz/std/6/58/25.png, so this will be the URL it will make a call to serve the request.

Comment: Hi Vitaliy ,  thank you for your reply.  I reviewing the setting, Restful Service now works properly.  thanks a lot.